# Some questions about realtime filter

Tags: filters, real-time

1. the sample rate of signal is 1khz,which filter method can i take to realize a 3-5ms delay.
2. I would like to ask if there is a way to pass the signal through a low-pass filter and then adjust it through PI to adjust the error and reduce the filter delay? Or is there another way to reduce the delay?

Comment: What kind of delay are we talking about? Processing delay, or group delay, or a combination thereof? If you're going for group delay, is it important that all frequencies experience the same group delay (which dictates a symmetrical FIR filter, because it's equivalent to demanding linear phase), or are you mainly concerned with the group delay of a single frequency or range of frequencies? Your second question is a bit strange- at least if you think in causal systems, all you can do is add more delay, not take delay away.

Comment: Honestly, I think this would be much nicer to answer if you could edit your question to include the actual use case of that filter. Something feels very off about your requirements, and together with thinking `filtfilt` was the right tool in your previous question, I think it's fair to assume you also come here to get advice on how to design your filter requirements, so don't be shy about describing your application in very concrete words!

Comment: It seems you might be concerned about the noise out of your error detector (for whatever kind of loop you have). Note that the error is typically quite noisy often with no consequence--it's the job of the loop filter together with the device controlled (if frequency selective) to reduce that noise. If you need more noise suppression, then your option is to tighten the loop bandwidth, increase the order of the loop, or both. As Marcus said, please add more details as to your ultimate goal.